# Best way to activate between 2 workbooks in a Application.OnTime loop VBA

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have `workbook1` which is connected to a data API. I wish to take a snapshot of the cell values every 5 seconds from `workbook1` and merge it onto the dataset in `workbook2` on the next empty row.

However I think my code doesn't properly switch between the two workbooks. As an example I have some hard numbers in `workbook1` and ran the macro. The code copies and paste the hard numbers from `workbook1` to `workbook2` as expected. However once I manually changed the numbers in `workbook1`, the macro fails the pick up the change on the subsequent merged rows in `workbook2`.

Can someone help?

```
Sub timer() 

If Hour(Time) <= 16 Then

Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "dataextract"

ElseIf Hour(Time) >= 18 Then

Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "dataextract"

End If

End Sub

Sub dataextract()

Dim Datetime As Date
Dim Bid As Single
Dim Ask As Single
Dim BidVol As Integer
Dim AskVol As Integer
Dim dataset As Workbook 

Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
Datetime = Range("B2")
Bid = Range("C2")
Ask = Range("D2")
BidVol = Range("E2")
AskVol = Range("F2")

Set dataset = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ali\Desktop\Dataset.xlsx") 'dataset is workbook2
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Select
RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")
.Offset(RowCount, 0) = Datetime
.Offset(RowCount, 1) = Bid
.Offset(RowCount, 2) = Ask
.Offset(RowCount, 3) = BidVol
.Offset(RowCount, 4) = AskVol
End With

dataset.Save

timer

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should test if the external workbook is open yet.

```
Sub timer()

    If Hour(Time) <= 16 Or Hour(Time) >= 18 Then

        Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "dataextract"

    End If

End Sub

Sub dataextract()
    Dim dataset As Workbook
    On Error Resume Next

    Set dataset = Workbooks("Dataset.xlsx")
    If dataset Is Nothing Then Set dataset = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ali\Desktop\Dataset.xlsx")

    On Error GoTo 0

    With dataset.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .Range("B" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

            .Resize(1, 5).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:F2")

        End With
    End With

    dataset.Save

    timer

End Sub
```

Comment: I get the error: "Object doesn't support this property or method" on `.Resize(1, 5).Values = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:F2")`. Could it be I'm using Excel 2013?

Comment: I updated my answer.  It should be .Value not .Values

Comment: The code runs now but it doesn't paste anything to `dataset.xlsx`... I mean I understand this line takes the range B2:F2 and paste it into the next empty row in `dataset.xlsx`... why does it paste empty?